# WCF service calls SSIS package, w3wp.exe memory keeps climbing

Tags: wcf, ssis, memory-leaks

My .net WCF service calls a SSIS package using the Package.Execute(); method.

After I call execute, I set pkg.Dispose() and app = null;

The memory usage keeps climbing, 100mb to 150mb all the way to almost 300mb.

I am recycling the process now, but want to know the source of the problem.

Any ideas?

**Update**
The application that calls the WCF service is on another server so there is no issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing your host?  Just using a using statement?  what does the open/close code look like?

Comment: Which host?  You mean:  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application  It doesn't have a close or dipose() ?

Comment: The application that calls the WCF service is on another server btw.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this quite common task (diagnose memory leaks in w3wp work processes). Tess has a great "getting started" post here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/05/21/debugdiag-1-1-or-windbg-which-one-should-i-use-and-how-do-i-gather-memory-dumps.aspx

- Oisin

Answer (score 0):

An increase in virtual memory is not necessarily a problem, and 300MB is not very much memory in any case. Does IIS recycle on its own? If not, then I suggest you leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running SSIS 05 or 08? I remember 05 having a known mem leak issue when called using the API.

HTH